# ExpressJs server along with command line interface

Tags: node.js, express, command-line-interface, prompt

I'm developing a REST API server using `express.js` but I would like to allow the developer to issue command trough the command line.

It is a development server that read a `config.json`, create endpoint and store data in-memory.

I would like to give the developer the ability to reload the base data without restarting the express server.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of what seems to me like a more elegant solution to your problem that you may be interested in: having the server automatically reload the `config.json` file whenever it changes. This is trivial to implement in Node.js:

```
const fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "config.json");
fs.watch(filePath, function(event) {
    if (event === "change") {
        var file = require(filePath); // require loads JSON as a JS object
        // do something with the newly loaded file here
        console.log("Detected change, config file automatically reloaded.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better option would be to add a route to the app like so (since the server will be blocking, and therefore not allow any command-line input on the same process):

```
"use strict";

const http = require("http"),
    path = require("path"),
    express = require("express"),
    PORT = 8000;

var app = express();

function loadConfigFile(callback) {
    var configFile = false;
    try { // load config file if it exists
        configFile = require(path.join(__dirname, "config.json"));
    } catch(e) { // ignore if the config file doesn't exist
        if (e.code !== "MODULE_NOT_FOUND") {
            throw e
        }
    }
    callback(configFile); // argument will be false if file does not exist
}

function authenticateAdminUser(req) { return true; } // dummy logic

app.get("/admin/reload", function(req, res, next) {
    if (!authenticateAdminUser(req)) {
        let err = new Error("Forbidden");
        err.StatusCode = 403;
        return next(err);
    }

    loadConfigFile(function(file) {
        if (file) {
            // do something with the file here
        }
        res.send("Reloaded config file successfully.");
    });
});

loadConfigFile(function(file) {
    if (file) {
        // do something with the file here
    }
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log("Server started on port " + PORT + ".");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is (more or less) how I'm handling this right now, but I think a CLI driven solution is much more elegant, but I'm facing the issue that `express` is blocking the input from cli...

Comment: In that case, you could keep the routing approach, and create a different Node.js command-line program that works by sending a request to the given routes (and perhaps identifying itself in some way, so that only its requests are handled); that way, you only need to use the CLI. There's no way to do it within the same process without stopping the server, because it will always be blocking.